# Unable to locate package `docker-ce` on a 64bit ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, apt, software-installation, docker

I'm trying to install Docker on a Ubuntu 64 machine following [the official installation guide](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntu/#install-using-the-repository).

Sadly Ubuntu seems it is not able to locate the `docker-ce` package. Any idea to fix it or at least to track what is happening ?

Here some details for you...

```
$ uname --all; sudo grep docker /etc/apt/sources.list; sudo apt-get install docker-ce

Linux ubuntu 4.4.0-62-generic #83-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 18 14:10:15 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial stable.
# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial stable.

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package docker-ce
```

Comment: Did you run `apt-get update` after adding the repo?

Comment: @jordanm yes, sorry I didn't post it in the question.

Answer (score 254, accepted):

#### Add Docker's official GPG key:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ca-certificates curl gnupg
sudo install -m 0755 -d /etc/apt/keyrings
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg
sudo chmod a+r /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg
```

#### Ubuntu 23.10 (Mantic Minotaur)

```
echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu mantic stable" | \
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
```

#### Ubuntu 23.04 (Lunar Lobster)

```
echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu lunar stable" | \
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
```

#### Ubuntu 22.10 (Kinetic)

```
echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu kinetic stable" | \
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
```

#### Ubuntu 22.04 (Jammy)

```
echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy stable" | \
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
```

#### Ubuntu 21.10 (Impish)

```
echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu impish stable" | \
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
```

#### Ubuntu 21.04 (hirsute)

```
echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu hirsute stable" | \
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
```

#### Ubuntu 20.10 (Groovy)

```
echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu groovy stable" | \
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
```

#### Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal)

```
echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal stable" | \
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
```

#### Ubuntu 19.10 (Eoan)

```
echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu eoan stable" | \
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
```

#### Ubuntu 19.04 (Disco)

```
echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu disco stable" | \
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
```

#### Ubuntu 18.10 (Cosmic)

```
echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu cosmic stable" | \
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
```

#### Ubuntu 18.04 (bionic)

```
echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable" | \
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
```

#### Ubuntu 17.10

```
echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu artful stable" | \
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
```

#### Ubuntu 16.04

```
echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial stable" | \
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
```

Run the following:

```
sudo apt update
apt-cache search docker-ce
```

sample output:

```
docker-ce - Docker: the open-source application container engine
```

Install `docker-ce`:

```
sudo apt install docker-ce
```

To check the available and permitted Ubuntu codenames:

```
curl -sSL  https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/ |awk -F'"' 'FNR >7 {print $2}'
```

sample output (Results may be different after the directory updates):

```
../
artful/
bionic/
cosmic/
disco/
eoan/
focal/
groovy/
hirsute/
impish/
jammy/
kinetic/
lunar/
trusty/
xenial/
yakkety/
zesty/
```

Docker , [OS requirements](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#os-requirements)

Comment: way better than https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/

Comment: why is it not in the official repositories?

Comment: It's worth mentioning that for Ubuntu 17.10, the step 3 would be: `sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu artful stable"`

Comment: still not in artful repository :(

Comment: docker not being in zesty -- but why not snap?  isn't the point of snap to install packages like this?

Comment: @GAD3R that's a good answer.  perhaps bull-headed of me, want to install with snap -- if do-able.  (I mean, it installs, but then...etc.  something about apparmor.)  I'll come back and try this at some point -- I'm sure it works :)

Comment: @MichaelWiles please see my answer for Ubuntu 17.10 (artful): https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/406952/102003

Comment: The instructions for 17.10 also worked for me in 18.04, when the official `docker-ce` install instructions did not. Maybe not recommended though, since it's from the `artful` repo?

Comment: Indeed for 18.04 bionic docker repo from test fixed the issue
sudo apt-get install docker-ce
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package docker-ce is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'docker-ce' has no installation candidate

Fix:    sudo add-apt-repository    "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   test"
sudo apt-get update
Install docker

Comment: I would recommend putting your updated answers on top and not at the bottom.  I ran the outdated answer before seeing the updated answer.

Comment: For ubuntu 19.04 I found @pwaterz comment useful, which only `sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable"
` worked. Note **bionic**

Comment: For Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic), I had to do: `sudo apt install docker-containerd docker-doc docker-runc docker.io` (still having problems running hello-world, but...)

Comment: @GAD3R It wasn't a question.

Comment: Worked well for Ubuntu 20.04.2: `$ sudo apt install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl software-properties-common && curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add - && sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal stable" && sudo apt install -y uidmap`

Comment: What about 21.10 (impish)? :)

Comment: @GAD3R Great 

Comment: Doesn't work on impish (`E: Unable to locate package docker-ce`). Had to revert `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list` to `hirsute`.

Answer (score 15):

For anyone who is using Ubuntu 17.10 (artful) and having this problem:

From https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/

> To install Docker CE, you need the 64-bit version of one of these
>   Ubuntu versions:
>
> Artful 17.10 (Docker CE 17.11 **Edge** only)
>
> Zesty 17.04
>
> Xenial 16.04
>
> (LTS) Trusty 14.04 (LTS)

and:

> To add the edge or test repository, add the word **edge** or test (or
>   both) after the word stable in the commands

So if you are using Ubuntu 17.10 (artful), you need to add this:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable edge"
```

Noticing "edge" word is added. If you already ran this command before without "edge". You can edit the `source.list` file at `/etc/apt/sources.list`. After that, refresh and install `docker-ce` as usual:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install docker-ce
```

Answer (score 5):

Try using:

```
$ curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -

$  sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"

$ sudo apt-get update
$  sudo apt install docker.io
```

Comment: when asked for version docker version, it gave hint to use $sudo apt install docker.io.. that ran successfully.

Comment: @HydTechie, The docs says that the old docker versions should be uninstalled, docker.io being one of the older versions: https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#uninstall-old-versions

Answer (score 3):

Looks like docker will be in official repository after December docker-ce release (stable). Then this repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu artful stable"
```

should work.
Meanwhile there should be soon available edge release on

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu artful edge"
```

But its not available now yet. But v17.11.0-ce-rc4 was released yesterday, so i would expect it any day now.

So for now I used package from 17.04 repo as GAD3R is [suggesting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/363058/261045).

[link](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/141) to github issue.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me.

I removed docker completely, then went and manually removed the docker files in `/var`.

Reinstalled and running perfectly afterwards.

Comment: FYI for 19.04 'disco' repo does not have docker-ce, you have to use bionic until it gets added. ```sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable"```

Comment: yup, same here today with `disco` have to use `bionic` packages instead.