# Docker Install Error: could not find a distribution template for Pop/groovy

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, docker, repository, pop-os

I'm trying to install Docker on my Pop_OS!

```bsh
gustavoeklund in ~ ❯ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Pop
Description:    Pop!_OS 20.10
Release:    20.10
Codename:   groovy
```

when I run the following commands:

```bsh
gustavoeklund in ~ ❯ curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
OK
gustavoeklund in ~ ❯ sudo add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable"
```

I got the following error:

```bsh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 330, in <module>
    addaptrepo = AddAptRepository()
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 35, in __init__
    self.distro.get_sources(self.sourceslist)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/distro.py", line 91, in get_sources
    raise NoDistroTemplateException(
aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a distribution template for Pop/groovy
```

Comment: Welcome, try this answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/363058/153195. (add `groovy` without `lsb_release -cs`)

Comment: stills giving exactly the same error with `sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu groovy stable"` -----> `aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a distribution template for Pop/groovy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the source manually (without `add-apt-repository`):

```
echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu groovy stable" |sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker-ce.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install docker-ce
```